# Safari 10 throws Content-Security-Policy violations

Tags: content-security-policy, safari10

Safari 10 throws a CSP-style-src-Violation in spite of calling a weg page with **no** style attributes inside.
The violation-message is:

> Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce, or
>   'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the style-src directive of the
>   Content Security Policy.

Test web page is:
[CSP test page](https://www.webtop.de/test.html)

The only addon installed is Adblock-Plus. After removing the addon, the violation is not shown anymore. The rendered html source shows no style-attribute at all, with adblock or without.

Is there a way how to filter out these false violation messages?
They are misleading.

Comment: is there a way to disable CSP check in safari?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue.looks like if you mention the style directive its expecting style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; hope it helps.

Comment: is there a way to disable CSP check in safari?